# Get tax of product in database

Tags: database, sql, query

I have this query to get the prices of all sold products of a shipping date:

```
SELECT ShippingDay,
       round(Sale_in_Euro,2) AS Sales,
FROM
SUM(SELECT (cped.value * sfoi.qty_ordered)
                 FROM catalog_product_entity_decimal AS cped
                 WHERE cped.entity_id = sfoi.product_id
                   AND cped.attribute_id = 99)) AS Sale_in_Euro
FROM sales_flat_order AS sfo
   INNER JOIN sales_flat_order_item AS sfoi ON sfoi.order_id=sfo.entity_id
   WHERE (sfo.status = 'processing'
          OR sfo.status = 'pending')
   GROUP BY sfo.shipping_arrival_date
   ORDER BY sfo.shipping_arrival_date DESC) AS resulttable
```

However `cped.value` is the value of the product including taxes. I now want to include that the taxes are substracted from the calculation, but I am a bit confused where to find the appropriate information.

I find the `tax_class_id` of the product in `catalog_product_index_price` - then there are other tables like `tax_calculation_rate` and `tax_calculation`, but how are they connected? Any suggestion how I can substract the taxes from the product prices in the query above?

And what is stored in `sales_order_tax_item`?